# RxSwift Driver weakly subscription?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I was looking for an easier way to pass function as parameter into Observable's `subscribe` method without causing retain cycle; I don't want to always have to use `[weak self]` every single time. I've just come across this [answer](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/issues/14), and it's exactly what I want. Even better, it's already being merged into the framework itself. However, I don't seem to find a similar method for `Driver`.

Has it already been implemented, and I'm just looking at the wrong place? If not, can you guide me how to add it? ... As a side note, how do you normally deal with all the `[weak self]` everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

> As a side note, how do you normally deal with all the `[weak self]` everywhere?

I rarely use `subscribe`, so I don't need `[weak self]` very often. Use `bind(to:)` as much as possible and you don't have to worry about self. Another option is to make a local reference and use it. For example:

```
let foo = self.foo
myObservable.subscribe(onNext: {
    // Use of 'foo' here will refer to the local foo, not self.foo.
    // Of course if foo is a class type, they will both refer to the 
    //   same object so that's fine.
    // No weak self necessary because self isn't part of the chain.
})
```